# What is the font used in Sega ads during the 90's?

Tags: font-identification

The font in which the phrase "GENESIS DOES WHAT NINTENDON'T" is written.
I want to use this font for the promotional material for the game I'm going to make. Can't find it anywhere on the internet. Please, help me if you know this!

[image]

Comment: In addition to what Ovaryraptor edit at my answer, the last two lines, I annex that the font identifiers by MyFont or Fontsquirrel don't work with distorted fonts. I tried it even by separating the characters. I think the Closing Tag is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Extension RR ExtraBold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/extension-rr/) via myfonts.com

[image]

Note that the text in the magazine appears to have its width and spacing altered from the original font.